# how to get the type of a deferred template parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

Is there a way to get the defered type of a class template parameter ?

```
template <class TPtr>
struct foo {
    typedef TPtr ptr_type;
    typedef ??? element_type; /* shall be the type of a deferred TPtr*/
};
```

so `foo<const char*>::element_type` results in `const char`, and `foo<std::vector<int>::iterator_type>::element_type` results in `int`.

i am aware of that i can use the `value_type` typedef for c++ iterators (like `std::vector<int>::iterator_type::value_type`), but raw pointers havent got a value_type typedef, so i am out of luck there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If `TPtr` can only be a pointer**, you're looking for [Boost's `remove_pointer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_pointer.html).

If you're wondering how in the world that works, it uses partial specialization in this manner:

```
template<typename T>
struct RemovePointer;

template<typename T>
struct RemovePointer<T*>
{
    typedef T Type;
};

int main()
{
    RemovePointer<int*>::Type foobar; // foobar has the type int
    return 0;
}
```

**If `TPtr` can be either an iterator or a pointer**, you need [the `iterator_traits` class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/), which is part of the standard library. In your case, it's used like this:

```
template <class TPtr> 
struct foo { 
    typedef TPtr ptr_type;
    // The compiler won't know for sure if value_type is actually
    // a type until TPtr is known. The typename keyword is a hint
    // to the compiler so it doesn't cause an error.
    typedef typename iterator_traits<TPtr>::value_type element_type;
};
```

Believe it or not, it works by partial specialization as well. It's basically defined like this:

```
// Primary template for iterators

template<class Iterator>
struct iterator_traits
{
    typedef typename Iterator::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename Iterator::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename Iterator::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename Iterator::reference reference;
    typedef typename Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
};

// Partial specializations for pointers

template<class T>
struct iterator_traits<T*>
{
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};

template<class T>
struct iterator_traits<const T*>
{
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef const T* pointer;
    typedef const T& reference;
    typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};
```

That's why the `iterator_traits` class works on both iterators and pointers.

Comment: Use the iterator solution for more a more generic approach. It will work with pointers.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a solution applicable to iterators.